# How to use groupby() in python for 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose this is my df:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsgBL.png]

I want to group this data by Month and Order ID like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U78P.png]

How can I use the groupby function properly?

I tried `sales_data.groupby(['Month', 'Order ID'])['Cost'].sum()` but it does not really give what I want.

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect? It would be helpful if you could provide your code snippet that doesn't work + elaborate on what is wrong with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `groupby()`+`agg()`

```
df=(df.groupby(['Month','Order ID'])
      .agg({'ItemOrdered':','.join,'Cost(Dollars)':'sum','Discount':'first'}))
```

Since you didn't provide your data as text so if 'discount' column is giving you wrong output then replace `'first'` inside `agg()` to `'sum'`